# Как правильно задавать последнюю позицию в grid-column (css)?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно задавать последнюю позицию колонке в ряду, если `grid-column-start: -1;` создает дополнительную (6) колонку с минимальной шириной?

Получилось выполнить задачу через `grid-column-start: -2;`, но насколько это правильно?

```css
.wrapper { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; 
} 
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(1)
{
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: -1;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.nested {
  border: 2px solid #ffec99;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff9db;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box1">6</div>
  <div class="box2">7</div>
  <div class="box3">8</div>
  <div class="box4">9</div>
  <div class="box5">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше  через `grid-column-start: 5;`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper> div:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: 5;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.nested {
  border: 2px solid #ffec99;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff9db;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box1">6</div>
  <div class="box2">7</div>
  <div class="box3">8</div>
  <div class="box4">9</div>
  <div class="box5">10</div>
</div>
```

> Если не известно точное количество колонок?

Тогда `grid-column-start: -2;`, так как отрицательные привязывают с конца.

`grid-column-start: -1;` привяжет к последний линии и создаст дополнительную колонку.

`grid-column-start: -2;` привяжет к предпоследней, что соответствует началу последней колонке.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper> div:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: -2;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.nested {
  border: 2px solid #ffec99;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff9db;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box1">6</div>
  <div class="box2">7</div>
  <div class="box3">8</div>
  <div class="box4">9</div>
  <div class="box5">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если не известно точное количество колонок?

Comment: тогда grid-column-start: -2;